# Hazelcast stuck in Frozen state

Tags: java, hazelcast

In my hazelcast cluster, Hazelcast seems to be stuck in FROZEN state and does not want to accept any new members.

What's the solution here?

`Cluster state either is locked or doesn't allow new members to join -> ClusterState{state=FROZEN, lock=ClusterStateLock{lockOwner=null, transactionId='null', lockExpiryTime=0}}`

From the documents, it appears that the cluster has fractured. I thought that if split brain syndrome occurs Hazelcast will automatically attempt to recover, but in this case it hasn't.

My cluster does NOT have a mapstore, it's a cluster used for vert.x clustering, so most of the data that is stored in hazelcast is event bus subscriptions.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you (or someone) explicitly change your cluster state to frozen? I don't recall that cluster can put itself into a frozen state.

Comment: @Nick, have you changed cluster state with API or ManCenter? Could you provide ways to reproduce?

Comment: @VikGamov the only thing that happened at the cluster is the services going up and down (possibly via sigkill). I did not modify the state of the cluster by hand. No good set of steps to reproduce sorry. 3 machines were up. Some of them were shut down and new machines were brought in (rolling deploy), if I am not mistaken.